# How to get credit for a new method that I invented?

Tags: writing, authorship, methodology

I'm a PhD student, and I invented a new method to assist and semi-automate the writing process. Since I need to add more papers to my CV I decided to teach some of my PhD student colleges the method and convince them to put me as a coauthor in one of their papers. I know getting a paper is quite hard, because I've written some during my PhD.

Since I could get trouble at work, how to do this is an elegant and professional way, like a technical assistant?

Comment: "I invented a new method to assist and semi-automate the writing process". Crank alert!! "I decided to teach some of my PhD student colleges the method and convince them to 'pay' me back putting me as a coauthor in one of their papers". Fraud alert!!! "student colleges" Perhaps your novel method could involve a grammar and spell-checker as well.

Comment: It would be unethical to list you as an author to any paper if you did not substantially contribute to it.

Comment: I could contribute substantially, such a statistician can do. The problem is that my job is not well valued.

Comment: @Alexandros, you don't know the method. It has mathematical and statistical basis. Also, you are deviated from the main question.

Comment: @biotech Where it was published? I could read it there. No need to put identifying information just mention the name of the journal.

Comment: Has not been published yet, is not yet formalized.

Comment: I was sure about that. So, publish first and then convince others to use it.

Comment: Ok @Alexandros. I will try to formalise it, but it could be already exploited. I'm already using it.

Comment: It is hard to beat Scigen (http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/scigen/) or mathgen (http://thatsmathematics.com/mathgen/)

Comment: When I completed my PhD, I was able to publish a handful of papers, I had a pretty good method too  -it was called hard work - this screams "lazy short cut" and worse, exploitation.

Comment: @santiago, correlation between 'hard work' and productivity is less than 1, other factors are involved.

Answer (score 7):

I, like many others, am skeptical that your new writing method is actually valid and/or useful.

If by some chance your method is actually valid and useful, however, then you should not be given a co-authorship by those who use the method.  Rather, they should *cite* your method, just like they would any method that they used in conducting the experimentation.

Comment: When too much information is available and decision-makeing becomes difficult, simplification is key. This is the basis of my method. Is a very high level method, doesn't care about details.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @jakebeal. I understood the way a person should be recognised their merits, and via publication and cites is fair, rather than co-authorship.

Answer (score 5):

You invented a new writing method? You're kidding, right? As far as I know, there exist only one writing method known to mankind, which hasn't changed much since the invention of writing. If you're talking about some NLP technique, not only it is likely not novel, but I think that the **value** of all that is close to zero and actually can be *damaging* to research and writing skills of potential users of such method and corresponding software.

However, what is more important and troubling is your planning of a rather *unethical* behavior with your "smart" payback scheme (unless you've poorly described your role). It is neither elegant, nor professional - the indication of that you can see in a series of downvoting of your question as well as comments. I would suggest you to reconsider your "shortcuts" approach to earning *academic reputation* or, at least, be careful with similar approaches, as they might be damaging career-wise.

The minimum requirements for an *authorship*, according to the [Vancouver protocol](http://www.icmje.org/recommendations) are:

- Conception, design, analysis and interpretation of data;
- Drafting an article or revising it critically for important  intellectual  content;
- Final approval of the version to be published.

Comment: The value of the method could be close to zero, but not zero. Thanks for your answer. NLP techniques seems similar to what I developed. I will have to read a bit more. I just want to help people, hope not considered as malintended.

Comment: @biotech: You're welcome. In regard to the value, it is difficult to assess that properly due to lack of details. In regard to your intentions, perhaps, you've described the situation not correctly, hence all that negative feedback. You can try to reformulate your question, but IMHO it doesn't make sense at this point, as, with a negative score of 3 or more, any question will not appear in the recent questions listing.

Comment: For now it's OK, I got enough feedback with your answers and people comments. I will try to formalise the method and back here again for help if necessary.